# AWS - Cloudfront / S3 - Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

[image]

My website is on AWS EC2 instance. It has Cloudfront & S3 bucket.

When I am trying to access my website. I am keep getting **Access Denied** error.

I am not sure what configuration I am missing.

Below is my bucket policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "MakePublic",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::domain-cdn/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Already followed https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3/

I am using Cloudfront & it is point to S3 bucket.

Comment: Some help here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3/. If that doesn't help, then please provide more information such as the S3 bucket policy contents.

Comment: HI @jarmod I added my bucket policy in question. Thanks

Comment: Did you read the knowledge center article? Your bucket policy is almost certainly not what you want - it allows unauthenticated list, write, and delete, for example. Set it up to allow CloudFront OAI read access per the article.

Comment: @AnkitShah Please edit your question to provide more details. For example, what are you doing when you get "Access Denied"? How have you configured CloudFront? How have you configured the origins to point to the EC2 instance and S3? More information, please!

Comment: Yes @JohnRotenstein all things are setup from EC2 -> Cloudfront -> S3

Comment: That's quite strange. What do you mean by `EC2 -> Cloudfront`? Are you saying that users directly access the web server on the Amazon EC2 instance, and that CloudFront is only used in front of the Amazon S3 bucket? It is quite common to put both behind CloudFront, which is why I am asking.

Comment: Are you certain your website is on EC2? What role is S3 playing here exactly? - Ideally S3 is used for static web hosting and EC2 might be running API server. Is that your case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

So from the server it is always looking for index.html file & giving 403 error.

By setting up below it resolved. Thanks

Comment: Have been battling myself silly for days with various CloudFront errors. I added the error and immediately the website became available. Thank you!

Comment: It worked for the same scenario. Can someone explain why it worked?

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling with Accessdemined error for couple of days by adding error page it has started working...

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Jackson is tempting (I tried it out and it indeed worked), but I knew that it is definitely not the way to go because a 403 should never be simply redirected to a 200. There is a better way to do this. **Note: skip to the last step if you are not hosting a static site.** This should resolve the permissions issue. In my case I was hosting a static site and needed to do all three.

**Enable static hosting:**
First, in your S3 bucket, go to properties and scroll to "Static website hosting". Enable that feature and make sure to specify your "index.html" file. After saving, scroll back to the static website hosting section and copy the "Bucket website endpoint" URL.

**Link to the new static host URL:**
Then, in your cloudfront distribution, go to the "Origins" tab and select your S3 origin. Click "Edit". For the origin domain, make sure to use the static website URL you copied in the last step.

**Fix permissions issues:**
Finally, you'll need to make your S3 bucket public. Here are two policies I found that I needed to make the Access Denied error go away. I put these in the S3 bucket policy section:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
        }
    ]
}
```